# How to download an Outlook attachments based on specific file name within the 24 hrs?

Tags: powershell, outlook, etl

I'm trying to download attachments within emails based on file name that have been received within the last 24 hour AND are the first match. The first match is in-case a second email with the same filename is received and needed to be output to the location. The files are received to the inbox typically once a day but there are times where it'll have to be handled via the 'latest received'. So wit that said, when there is a match, the code supposed to grab the files and put the first matched files to the location and then stop / terminate the script.

However, it doesn't seem to take the time factor into account at all. At this point my code finds the first matched two files based on the filename, and dumps them into the location. Then it keeps overwriting the files as it finds older files with the same name within the inbox.

In this latest build / attempt, I'm using `$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)` as well as `-and ($_.CreationTime -lt $limit)` in my code. I've tried a number of methods but nothing seems to work.

```
    $account = 'blah@stihlse.com'
    $targetFolder = 'inbox'
    $f = $account.Folders | ? { $_.Name -match 'inbox'};
    $email = $f.Items|  Sort-Object ReceivedTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 
    $limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
    $filepath = "\\servername\home\blah\Documents\blah's emails"
    $ol = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
    $ns = $ol.GetNamespace('MAPI')
    $acct = $ns.Folders[$account]
$acct.Folders[$targetFolder].Items | foreach {
    if ($_.ReceivedTime -match $email -and ($_.CreationTime -eq $limit)) { 
            $_.attachments |
            foreach {
                Write-Host "attached file: ",$_.filename
                If ($_.filename -match 'BlahCompletions' -or $_.filename -match 'BlahCertifications'){
                    $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $_.FileName))
                } 
            } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `CreationTime -eq $limit`. `-eq` means equal. So it only works if the `CreationTime` is the exact same microsecond as `$limit`. What you are looking for is `-gt` (greater than) or `-ge` (greater or equal).

The other problem is `$_.ReceivedTime -match $email`. It is trying to `-match` the `ReceivedTime` to an regex. But the regex you provide is the whole `$email`. Take a look at [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#-match-and--notmatch)

Comment: Thank you for the input. I knew it was something simple that was tripping me up. As soon as made a few changes such as going with -ge . . .  it works the way I'm expecting it to.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you are iterating over all items in the folder:

```
$acct.Folders[$targetFolder].Items | foreach {
    if ($_.ReceivedTime -match $email -and ($_.CreationTime -eq $limit)) {
```

Which is really is not a good idea if you have a large number items in the folder. Instead, you need to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

For example, to get only items that has attachments onboard you can use the following condition:

```
query ="@SQL=" & chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & chr(34) & "=1"
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the information! You are right, that was one of the issues I was seeing even when the code worked the way I wanted. I had a 'workaround' where I simply set up a sub folder and had all the emails with the file name be dumped in there. Your solution obviously seems like a much more efficient / better solution. I'll have to dive into the articles you linked to learn more about those methods you referenced.